# for which $\sigma$-algebra this set function is a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Lets say we have $X=\mathbb{R}$, and we have the following function 
$$\mu(A)=\cases{0, \text{if  $A=\emptyset$}\\ 1, \text{if $A\neq \emptyset$}}$$

I am asked to say for which $\sigma$-algebra the latter is a measure.

First, it's easy to see that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, and I know that the measure must satisfy $\sigma$-additivity. My guess goes as follows:

Suppose $A_1,A_2\in X$, $A_1, A_2 \neq \emptyset$ and $A_1, A_2$ are disjoint.

Let $A=A_1\bigcup A_2$, hence $A\neq \emptyset$ and hence $\mu(A)=1$.

But if we use the $\sigma$-additivity we have that 
$$\mu(A_1\bigcup A_2)=1+1=2$$

So I suppose that the $\sigma$-algebra must be something like $\{X,\emptyset\}$

Is this correct? If this is not the right approach, how could I face this kind of problems?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: It is correct. It can be done slightly nicer. Assume there is $A\neq \emptyset, X$ measurable. Then we have $$ 1 = \mu(X)= \mu(A)+ \mu (X\setminus A) =1+1$$ yielding a contradiction.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for the alternative answer, yours is much more direct and clear!

Comment: Actually it is exactly the same as you did, just written in a different way. I suggest that you write an answer yourself with all the details. Then this gets off the unanswered list and you are sure that you understand everything.